# Импорт обученной и сохраненной в Python модели нейронной сети в Java

Tags: java, python, java-8, keras, deeplearning4j

Пытаюсь импортировать в Java обученную и сохраненную в Python модель нейронной сети.
Выдает следующее исключение:

> > Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/deeplearning4j/nn/weights/IWeightInit at
> >     org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.layers.core.KerasDense.(KerasDense.java:96)
> >     at
> >     org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.utils.KerasLayerUtils.getKerasLayerFromConfig(KerasLayerUtils.java:220)
> >     at
> >     org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.KerasModel.prepareLayers(KerasModel.java:218)
> >     at
> >     org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.KerasSequentialModel.(KerasSequentialModel.java:110)
> >     at
> >     org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.KerasSequentialModel.(KerasSequentialModel.java:57)
> >     at
> >     org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.utils.KerasModelBuilder.buildSequential(KerasModelBuilder.java:322)
> >     at
> >     org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.KerasModelImport.importKerasSequentialModelAndWeights(KerasModelImport.java:223)
> >     at NeuralNetwork.main(NeuralNetwork.java:21) Caused by:
> >     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> >     org.deeplearning4j.nn.weights.IWeightInit at
> >     java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) at
> >     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) at
> >     sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) at
> >     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) … 8 more

При чем если смотреть через отладчик, то он вроде как считывает H5 файл (см. картинку).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Модель нейронной сети, построенная и сохраненная в Python:

```
model_fully_connected = Sequential()
model_fully_connected.add(keras.layers.Dense(17, activation='tanh', input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],), W_regularizer=l2(l2_lambda)))
model_fully_connected.add(keras.layers.Dense(17, activation='tanh', W_regularizer=l2(l2_lambda)))
model_fully_connected.add(keras.layers.LeakyReLU (alpha=0.1))
model_fully_connected.add(keras.layers.Dense(17, activation='tanh', W_regularizer=l2(l2_lambda)))
model_fully_connected.add(keras.layers.LeakyReLU (alpha=0.1))
model_fully_connected.add(keras.layers.Dense(17, activation='tanh', W_regularizer=l2(l2_lambda)))
model_fully_connected.add(keras.layers.Dense(1))
model_fully_connected.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=["mae", "mse"])
history=model_fully_connected.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=1, verbose=2, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
# #Сохранение обученной нейронной сети
model_fully_connected.save("trained _neural_network.H5",True,True)
```

Ошибку выдает во время импорта, не один из ексепшенов не срабатывает.
Код импорта в Java:

```
MultiLayerNetwork modelMultiLayer=null;
        KerasModelImport kerasModelImport=new KerasModelImport();
        try {            modelMultiLayer=kerasModelImport.importKerasSequentialModelAndWeights("E:\\Java\\neuralwork\\trained _neural_network.H5");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKerasConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedKerasConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(modelMultiLayer.conf());
```

Библиотеки, которые использую в Java для импорта:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>deeplearning4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-beta2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>nd4j-native-platform</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-beta2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>deeplearning4j-modelimport</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-beta7</version>
        </dependency>
```

В чем здесь проблема?

Comment: Похоже, что надо добавить в зависимости deeplearning4j-nn

Comment: Получилось без добавления данной зависимости, она уже входит в какую-то из перечисленных, а вот версии нужно было везде одинаковые поставить и более новые, тогда заработало

Answer (score 0):

Версии нужно было везде одинаковые поставить и более новые. Рабочая конфигурация зависимостей для импорта многослойной полносвязанной нейронки с весами (обученной):

```
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>deeplearning4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-beta7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>nd4j-native-platform</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-beta7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>deeplearning4j-modelimport</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-beta7</version>
        </dependency>
```